# operator modulo change in c++ 11?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, modulo, c++03

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ operator % guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710801/c-operator-guarantees)

In c++ 98/03

5.6-4

> The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator
>   yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the
>   second. If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is
>   undefined; otherwise (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a. **If both operands
>   are nonnegative then the remainder is nonnegative; if not, the sign of
>   the remainder is implementation-defined**.

In c++ 11:

5.6 -4

> The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator
>   yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the
>   second. If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is
>   undefined. For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic
>   quotient with any fractional part discarded;81 if the quotient a/b is
>   representable in the type of the result, (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a.

As you can see the implementation-defined for the sign bit is missing, what happens to it ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? And how this comes as a obstacle for that?

Comment: @AnandVeeramani: some people just want to avoid undefined (or, in this case, implementation-defined) behavior. I'm glad he asked this, I have avoided modulo when the values could have been negative.

Comment: Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3609572/485561

Comment: C++ 98/03 also had this footnote: "According to work underway toward the revision of ISO C, the preferred algorithm for integer division follows the rules defined in the ISO Fortran standard, ISO/IEC 1539:1991, in which the quotient is always rounded toward zero"  C++11 simply made that a requirement of the standard (as C99 did for C). Removing the implementation defined part of the `%` operator is a consequence of that.

Comment: @moswald: you would have to avoid using `/` operator in those cases as well, since it is similarly implementation defined.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: In C++ 11 & C99 it's standard defined ?

Comment: @Gob00st: as mentioned in the answers, the behavior of the `/` operator for integral operands in C++11 is required to truncate toward zero.  That is also true in C99.  Prior standards left it implementation defined. Note that the `div()` function (and relatives) have always been specified to truncate toward zero.

Comment: Truncation towards zero was the *de facto* standard in C89 implementations; all C99 did was codify it.

Comment: A good [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) on the topic.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The behaviour of `%` was tightened in C++11, and is now fully specified (apart from division by `0`).

The combination of truncation towards zero and the identity `(a/b)*b + a%b == a` implies that `a%b` is always positive for positive `a` and negative for negative `a`.

---

The mathematical reason for this is as follows:

Let `÷` be mathematical division, and `/` be C++ division.

For any a and b, we have `a÷b = a/b + f` (where f is the fractional part), and from the standard, we also have `(a/b)*b + a%b == a`.

`a/b` is known to truncate towards `0`, so we know that the fractional part will always be positive if `a÷b` is positive, and negative is `a÷b` is negative:

`sign(f) == sign(a)*sign(b)`

`a÷b = a/b + f` can be rearranged to give `a/b = a÷b - f`. `a` can be expanded as `(a÷b)*b`:

`(a/b)*b + a%b == a` => `(a÷b - f)*b+a%b == (a÷b)*b`.

Now the left hand side can also be expanded:

`(a÷b)*b - f*b + a%b == (a÷b)*b`

`a%b == f*b`

Recall from earlier that `sign(f)==sign(a)*sign(b)`, so:

`sign(a%b) == sign(f*b) == sign(a)*sign(b)*sign(b) == sign(a)`

Comment: @mata: The sign is only determined by `a`, you have messed up the arithmetic there (-1/2) = -0.5 = 0 (after truncation), so 0 + x = -1, so x = -1.

Comment: @Mankarse:The equation is always there (as in 03 standard), the only thing new seems to be what's so called 'truncation towards zero'. What this 'truncation towards zero' all about ?

Comment: @Gob00st: Truncation towards zero means that the fractional part of the result of a division is discarded in the result, so 5/4 == 1.25 => 1 (discard 0.25), and -7/4 == -1.75 => -1 (discard -0.75).

Comment: Yes that's always there isn't it ? What I meant was how's this implies "that a%b is always positive for positive a and negative for negative a." ? Whereas in 03 standard is not.

Comment: @Gob00st: See my edit, in C++03, we could not be sure that `sign(f)==sign(a)*sign(b)`.

Comment: @Gob00st The other difference is *"For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded"*, which perfectly specifies the behaviour of `a/b`. So now together with the equation `a = (a/b)*b + a%b`, we get perfectly specified behaviour and there is no need for any implementation-defined behaviour with negative operands.

Comment: Now I got it after read this & the other post about truncation towards 0 defined in C99(not in C89).Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where can I find the information of changes in C++11 such as the behavior of the modulus operator % ? The websites I've found about the new features of C++ 11 don't mention the changes in the modulus operator. Do I need to buy the C++ Standard from ISO? Isn't this info about C++ available free of charge?

Comment: @JorgeLuque: Technically you need to buy the C++ Standard from ISO of from one of the national standards bodies, but the [final draft of the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) is freely available, and is usually very very similar to the official standard. See [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard).

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm says `(a/b)*b + a%b = a`, which is easier to read if you remember that it's `truncate(a/b)*b + a%b = a`  Using algebra, `a%b = a - truncate(a/b)*b`.  That is to say, `f(a,b) = a - truncate(a/b)*b`.  For what values is `f(a,b) < 0`?

It doesn't matter if `b` is negative or positive.  It cancels itself out because it appears in the numerator and the denominator.  Even if `truncate(a/b) = 0` and `b` is negative, well, it's going to be canceled out when it's a product of `0`.

Therefore, it is only the sign of `a` that determines the sign of `f(a,b)`, or `a%b`.

Comment: The equation is always there as in 03 standard as well ...

Comment: @Gob00st: The difference is that in C++03, rounding of divisions was not fully specified.