# Normalizing an Angle to the range 0 to 360 degrees?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, angle

We have the data type [Angle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/angle) in SwiftUI. This can store a value in degrees or radians from -infinity to +infinity.

I'd like to convert the angle to a value between 0 to 360. E.g. via using a method such as [wrap around mod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785443/is-there-an-expression-using-modulo-to-do-backwards-wrap-around-reverse-overfl):

```
func normalize(_ angle: Angle) -> Angle {
  wrapAroundMod(angle.degrees, 360.0)
}
```

However, `wrapAroundMod` isn't a built-in function, and wouldn't support floating point numbers. I'm struggling to come up with an elegant solution that doesn't have a bunch of branching logic.

Is there an elegant approach to normalizing an Angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elegant is in the eye of the beholder...

You can accomplish this without using a branch by using two applications of `truncatingRemainder(dividingBy:)`:

```
extension Angle {
    /// Returns an Angle in the range `0° ..< 360°`
    func normalized() -> Angle {
        let degrees = (self.degrees.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360) + 360)
                      .truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)

        return Angle(degrees: degrees)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this any better than a branch? Performance? I don't know the implementation of `truncatingRemainder(dividingBy:)` but I assume it would be more expensive than just a branch.

Comment: @George This is definitely not an expensive operation.

Comment: @LeoDabus Expensive was probably the wrong word, but is it actually better than `if degrees < 0 { degrees = degrees + 360 }`? I really don't know, I'm curious. I assume the difference might just be negligible for this task?

Comment: @George Yes I think both approaches would work just fine. I would prefer to work directly on radians as most methods rely on radians and the natural measure for dividing a circle is in radians.

Comment: @vacawama  no need to use a var. Btw the radians version would look like `var normalized: Self { .init(radians: (radians.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 2 * .pi) + 2 * .pi).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 2 * .pi)) }`

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of `%` for floating point numbers is `truncatingRemainder`, and it handles negative values pretty well!

You can use this function to normalize an angle:

```
extension Angle {
  /// Returns an Angle in the range `0° ..< 360°`
  func normalized() -> Angle {
    var degrees = self.degrees.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)
    if degrees < 0 {
      degrees = degrees + 360
    }
    return Angle(degrees: degrees)
  }
}
```

If you want to normalize it in the range `-180° ..< 180°`, consider adding this extension too:

```
extension Angle {
  /// Returns an Angle in the range `-180° ..< 180°` by mapping `180° ..< 360°` to `-180° ..< 0°`
  func normalizedDelta() -> Angle {
    var normalized = normalized()
    if normalized >= Angle(degrees: 180) {
      normalized = normalized - Angle(degrees: 360)
    }
    return normalized
  }
}
```

These functions have the properties:

```
Angle(degrees: -1081).normalized().degrees == 359
Angle(degrees: -721).normalized().degrees == 359
Angle(degrees: -361).normalized().degrees == 359
Angle(degrees: -1).normalized().degrees == 359
Angle(degrees: 0).normalized().degrees == 0
Angle(degrees: 359.9).normalized().degrees == 359.9
Angle(degrees: 360).normalized().degrees == 0
Angle(degrees: 361).normalized().degrees == 1
Angle(degrees: 720).normalized().degrees == 0
Angle(degrees: 721).normalized().degrees == 1
Angle(degrees: 1081).normalized().degrees == 1

Angle(degrees: -1081).normalizedDelta().degrees // == -1
Angle(degrees: -721).normalizedDelta().degrees // == -1
Angle(degrees: -361).normalizedDelta().degrees // == -1
Angle(degrees: -1).normalizedDelta().degrees // == -1
Angle(degrees: 0).normalizedDelta().degrees == 0
Angle(degrees: 359.9).normalizedDelta().degrees // == -0.1
Angle(degrees: 360).normalizedDelta().degrees == 0
Angle(degrees: 361).normalizedDelta().degrees == 1
Angle(degrees: 720).normalizedDelta().degrees == 0
Angle(degrees: 721).normalizedDelta().degrees == 1
Angle(degrees: 1081).normalizedDelta().degrees == 1
```

Comment: I think you would use this `.normalized()` in saving data or kind of this works or math works, because there is big deference for SwiftUI between 0 and 360 or 720 degrees. In animation and in View render they are not same.

Comment: `degrees += 360` and `normalized -= Angle(degrees: 360)`