# Find vector elements with even values

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, bind

Could you explain how does this code work. It successfully counts vector elements with even values, but it's not clear for me how does binding in this particular case work.

```
count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
         std::bind(logical_not<bool>(),
                   std::bind(modulus<int>(), placeholders::_1, 2)));
```

Comment: How about posting a COMPLETE code example, u now.

Comment: Anyway, you should simply *not use* code that you don't understand. If it's difficult for you then it's difficult for maintainers. So, re-express the effect in a way that you do understand.

Comment: [Here's an SSCCE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6a841c14269bfe7)

Comment: You could replace that mess with `[](int x){return x % 2 != 0;}`

Comment: http://ideone.com/80VmsZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the code you posted counts the **even** numbers in the vector, *not* the odd ones:

> ```
> count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
>          bind(logical_not<bool>(),
>               bind(modulus<int>(), placeholders::_1, 2)));
> ```

The `count_if` is an algorithm that returns the number of elements in the specified range satisfying specific criteria:

```
count_if(first, last, criteria)
```

In your case, `first` is `vec.begin()` and `last` is `vec.end()`: so the whole vector is considered for the count.

Now let's focus the attention on the criteria part.

Starting from inner and going outer:

`modulus<int>` is a [function object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/356950/1629821) that returns the remainder of an integer division (just like `%` operator). It takes two arguments: the first is expressed as `placeholders::_1`, which is the generic element in the source vector. Think of it as a variable `x` that scans the entire vector content.

The second argument is the number `2`, since to check if an integer is even or odd, you can calculate `x % 2` and compare the result with 0:

```
x % 2 == 0 --> even number
x % 2 == 1 --> odd number
```

`bind` is used to specify the arguments of the `modulus` function object.

The result of this modulus operation is given as input to another [function object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/356950/1629821): `logical_not<bool>`. This just negates the input, e.g. if the input was `false` (0), `logical_not<bool>` returns `true`, and viceversa.

So, the "counting criteria" is expressed by this flow of operations:

1. Calculate: `placeholders::_1 % 2`, i.e. `<<generic vector element>> % 2`, using `modulus`.
2. If the result of the above operation is `0` (false), return `true` (and viceversa), using `logical_not`.

So, if a number is even:

1. `even number % 2 == 0`
2. negating 0 you get `true`.

Instead, if a number is odd:

1. `odd number % 2 == 1`
2. negating 1 you get `false`.

Since `count_if` counts the number of elements for which the criteria is `true`, you are counting the *even* numbers in the vector.

If you really want to count the *odd* numbers in the vector, you can just get rid of the logical inversion (i.e. `logical_not`):

```
auto odds = count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                     bind(modulus<int>(), placeholders::_1, 2));
```

---

Note that in this case the functional approach using `modulus` and `logical_not` seems too complicated: using a **lambda** (or even an *ad hoc* `IsEven()` *simple function*) would be clearer.
Consider the following code ([live here on Ideone](http://ideone.com/rjkQEZ)) for a comparison between the three approaches:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool IsEven(int n) {
    return (n % 2) == 0;
}

int main() {
    // Test vector
    vector<int> vec{ 11, 22, 33, 44, 55 };

    // Using functional approach
    auto n = count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
         bind(logical_not<bool>(),
             bind(modulus<int>(), placeholders::_1, 2)));    
    cout << n << endl;

    // Using lambdas
    n = count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
                 [](int n) { return (n % 2) == 0; });
    cout << n << endl;

    // Using boolean returning ad hoc function
    n = count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), IsEven);
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unravel from inner call to outer call:

```
modulus<int>( a, 2 )
```

returns the remainder of something after a division by 2: ==0 or !=0.

```
logical_not<bool>( x )
```

does a logical inversion of x (so 0/false becomes 1/true and 1/true becomes 0/false)

```
count_if(from, to, cond )
```

evaluates cond (the inverted modulus) for all elements defined by the iterator from/to.

And the `placeholders::_1` is the hardwired way for inserting something determined in the iterator-driven loop run by `count_if` (i.e., the current element) into the function nested down below.

Comment: *"returns the remainder of something after a division by 2: 0 or 1."* Beware: the possible results are -1, +1 and 0 for `int`

Comment: @dyp thanks for suggestions to improve -- being precise is always best ;-)

Comment: @dyp remainder cannot be negative, it is always positive, x%2 returns 0 or 1

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 Not in C++11, and in C++03 the sign was implementation-defined. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13100805/420683

Answer (score 1):

**This doesn't count odd elements but even elements.**

To count vector elements with odd values we have to check each element for division by 2 and return true if the result is 1.

So we will use the modulus(), which is a function object that implements operator()

```
constexpr T operator()( const T& lhs, const T& rhs ) const;
```

and returns the remainder of the division of lhs by rhs.

We have to use std::bind to glue one and only one argument passed to

```
count_if( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p )
```

unary predicate `p` (which is our modulus here) to first argument of modulus and constant `2` to second

```
std::bind(modulus<int>(), placeholders::_1, 2))
```

Now our function `std::bind(modulus<int>(), placeholders::_1, 2))` returns **true** (1) if argument is **odd** and false (0) if argument is even. If we want to count even arguments we must neglect this, so our predicate must return the opposite:

```
std::bind(logical_not<bool>(),
                           std::bind(modulus<int>(), placeholders::_1, 2))
```

http://ideone.com/80VmsZ

As Mike Seymour suggested, simpler and cleaner design would be to replace this binds with short lambda function:

```
[](int x){return x % 2 == 0;} // to count even elements
[](int x){return x % 2 != 0;} // to count odds
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a double bind, first one computes the `modulus` by 2 of the argument, which seems to be the equivalent of

```
y = x % 2
```

And then the result is bound to `logical_not`, to reverse the result.

Comment: Ok this sounds reasonable. But why second binding needs to use placeholder::_1 . Why code does not work with placeholder::_2?

Comment: @user3548972: Because you want `var % 2` and not `2 % var`.