# Using modulus operator with floats

Tags: c++, floating-point

Somebody asked this question on a programming contest:-

-1%1000000009 is -1 or 1000000008

I want to know, is this even possible?
I tried in my system, got -1 every time.
Also, I had to find out 10^-9 % 10^9, I used fmod and got answer 1e-009, shouldn't it be 1?

My interpretation:-
10^-9/10^9 = 1/10^18
So, answer = 1.

Please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: As to your `fmod` question: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de).

Comment: @Jongware I am writing a program, so I need a clear view of what happens inside the program. This isn't helping. Any other help?

Comment: `%` is not a floating-point operator

Comment: Improve your title please so that the question stands out

Comment: you need to differentiate modulo and remainder operation. In C, Java and most other languages it's remainder and produce -1 while python and some environments have true modulus operations and return 1000000008

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461486/what-are-the-rules-for-modular-arithmetic-in-c?lq=1 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683563/whats-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder

Comment: My link is regarding the inaccuracies of floating point operations. That is why you get a small value where one would expect zero (*not* "1").

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074869/why-is-the-behavior-of-the-modulo-operator-different-between-c-and-ruby-for?lq=1

Comment: @Jongware: Huh?  No.  You wouldn't expect zero from that.  That would make no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

preview :  ( i will refer `mod` as `%`)

Just like in  `1%3` , we  do  `(int) 1/3` which is `0` , and then we ask : how many to add in order to get `1` ?

the answer is 1.

so `1%3=1`.

---

Looking at `10^-9 % 10^9`

let's use another numbers , for clarity :

`2^-3 % 2^3`

first we calc the integer value of the deviation:

`2^-3 / 2^3 = 1/(2^3 * 2^3) = 1/64`

as you can see it's a small number

so the int part is 0.

so  - how many to add in order to get `2^-3` ? that's right : `2^-3`

---

regarding your exact question :

> My interpretation:- 10^-9/10^9 = 1/10^18 So, answer = 1.

`1/10^18` indeed.

what's the integer part ? a **zero**.

from that zero , how much we need to add to get to `-1` ?

yup , `-1`.

just follow the rules of Modulo .

first find the integer deviation. and then ask : how much we need to add in order to get to numerator .

## edit:

for a situation where numerator >denominator

`7 % 5 = > 7 /5 => 1.4 => .4 go to hell = > you're left with 1.`

but notice.

**this is 1 times 5.**

ok so from 1 times 5  - how much it takes to go to 7 ? yes : 2.

more advanced :

`3.111 %2 = > 3.111/2 = > 1.5555 => .555 go to hell => you're left with 1.`

but that's 1 times of 2.

so from 1 times of 2 - how much it takes to go to 3.111 ?  yup 1.111

Comment: Does it mean that in every case such that numerator is a floating point and denominator is integer type and quite bigger than the float, the answer would be the float(initially numerator) only?

Comment: @user3715736 even if the numerator has float with oranges and the denominator has apples with integers : you first(!) take the iteger part of the result(!) so `2.111 % 3 => 2.111/3 =>0.7033 => .7033 go to hell => you're left with 0 => so how much we need to get to 2.111 ? 2.111`

Comment: `%` doesn't work with floating-point types. You can't write `3.111 % 2`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc my whole answer was on the math perspective. and i refer to `%` as Modulo.( I use c# and it's valid statement).

Comment: in that case use symbols like `mod` is better

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc Its just the notation, I have mentioned that I used fmod. Thanks btw!

Comment: float can't store such large precision and won't produce the correct result