# Modulus and unsigned integer

Tags: c++, unsigned, modulus

I found the following behavior surprising:

```
int a = -2;
int b = 5;
uint c = 5;
std::cout << a%b << '\n';
std::cout << a%c << '\n';

Output:
-2
4
```

When [comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5416414/1264299) are involved, mixing signed and unsigned is problematic - is there a hidden comparison in the operator `%`, or is there something else taking place here?

Comment: Note that a%b could also be 3. It is implementation defined weather % on negative numbers has a positive or negative result.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Not since C++11.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12711070/1264299

Comment: That link doesn't mention weather / must round towards 0 or down. The quoted C++11 part only say `(a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a`. It at least used to be that a / b would round differently on different CPUs and the standard allowed that. The % then changes to preserve the mentioned equality.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow When it says "*For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded*", I understand it to mean that a truncation is done - therefore, "rounding" to zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `uint` is an `unsigned` type no *narrower* than `int`, in the evaluation of the expression `a % c`, `a` is converted to `uint` and it will have the value `-2 + std::numeric_limits<uint>::max() + 1`.

For a 32 bit `uint`, that number is 4294967294, which modulo 5 is 4.

For a 16 bit `uint`, that number is 65534, which modulo 5 is, again, 4.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion

Comment: Thanks. Ok, so there's no comparison, but `%` triggers the same conversion. Can you indicate a place where that's documented?

Comment: @stafusa: I've added a reference that virtually proxies the standard.

Comment: Ah, ok - I had searched for "modulus" and then missed that: "The arguments of the following arithmetic operators undergo implicit conversions for the purpose of obtaining the common real type, which is the type in which the calculation is performed:

    binary arithmetic *, /, %, +, - "

Comment: @stafusa: Exactly! Do feel free to cobble all this together and answer your own question. I'd upvote it.