# Alternative of modulo operator in embedded C?

Tags: c, embedded

is there any alternative of % operator in embedded c ? there are some other ways of doing it such as using while loops in c++. but is it true that modulo operators slow down microcontroller systems ?

Comment: this seems to be like a duplicate question, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053/is-there-an-alternative-to-using-modulus-in-c-c

Comment: What do you want to do with the modulo operator?

Comment: there is two approachs to calculation of modulo function: - **Barrett Reduction** - **Montgomery Reduction** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7gyz.png)

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not the modulo operator slows down embedded systems depends a lot on *which* embedded systems you're discussing.

For example, the MPS430 CPU doesn't actually *have* a native divide instruction so, if you're using that, it will need to revert to a software-based calculation.

However, CPUs that *do* have a native divide will generally be okay, so it's best to first *test* whether you have a problem before you attempt to solve it.

---

Without a native divide instruction, your first attempt will be something like (C, for unsigned only and ignoring issues where `div` is zero for now):

```
unsigned modulo (unsigned num, unsigned div) {
    while (num >= div)
        num -= div;
    return num;
}
```

In other words, using repeated subtraction, something that's not going to be blindingly fast if `num` is large and `div` is small.

However, you can considerably ramp up the speed of that function if you just realise that `a % b` is exactly the same as `a % 2b`, provided that `2b <= a`.

Or that it's the same as `a % 4b`, provided that `4b <= a`. Ditto for `a % 8b`, provided that `8b <= a`.

So, with a little recursive magic, we can adjust `num` so that it reduces very fast to the point where repeated subtractions *won't* be a major issue.

```
unsigned modulo (unsigned num, unsigned div) {
    if (num - div >= div)
        num = modulo (num, div + div);
    while (num >= div)
        num -= div;
    return num;
}
```

Whereas the naive code sample takes about ten seconds on my system to process a hundred modulo operations (using a random number for `num` and a random number between one and a hundred for `div`), the improved solution can get through a million in about a third of a second, a speed-up of some 300,000 times.

You can also speed things up considerably if you know that your divisor is a power of two - there's a much faster way using bitwise operations. Consider that you want to work out:

```
974 % 16
```

You can also use the properties of binary numbers and bitwise operations to give you the lower four bits:

```
num = num & 15;
```

That's because `15` is `1111` in binary and, if you `and` any number with that, it will simply clear the top bits, giving you the same result as `mod 16`. This works for all powers of two such as `2`, `4`, `8`, ... `65536`, ..., and so on.

For the specific example of `974 % 16`, the binary for `974` bitwise-anded with `15`, gives:

```
1111001110
      1111 &
----------
0000001110 (14)
```

and `14` is *indeed* the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

One can divide with the modulo number and the subtract the result from the original number. This is not faster than the original modulo method.

Modulo contains division which can be slow on some embedded processors.

There are exceptions which can be performed faster. Modulo for 2, 4, 8, 16 and so on can be obtained by a simple AND operation which is very fast.