# Most efficient way to "clip" a value to repeat through a range?

Tags: c, math

Given a value `n`, what would be the most efficient way of putting it in the range of `[min, max]` such that it will repeat through the range if it goes beyond it?

I don't know the term for this, so it's difficult to phrase the question, but maybe a truth table might help:

Where `min = -2` and `max = 3`

```
 input  --> output
    -6      0
    -5      1
    -4      2
    -3      3
    -2     -2
    -1     -1
     0      0
     1      1
     2      2
     3     -2
     4     -1
     5      0
     6      1
```

What I have so far is this:

```
(value - min) % (max - min) + min;
```

Which works, but my worry is the modulus operator `%` is unreliable for negative inputs, from what I've read (output becomes implementation defined, rendering it useless, or at least unportable)

Comment: Why not take the modulus of the absolute value?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Is this the equation you're looking for  ?
`x % (max - min) + min`

Comment: @MichaelWalz - I added it, and also fixed the truth table (the last three entries were incorrect)

Comment: shouldn't the output for 3 be 3...???!!!!

Comment: @2rd_7 - the modulus operator turns `3%3` to 0, so I just based the range around it (sorry, I initially messed that part up in the question)

Comment: I suggest for clarity, the post should be retitled into something like: _Most efficient way of “clipping” values to **wrap inside** a range?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is like this:

```
min = VALUE;
max = VALUE;
x = (((x - min) + 1) % (max - min)) + min
```

here x will be inside min and max - 1 when you repeat the last line of code

EDIT:

and to match your exact table:

```
output = (input - min) % (max - min) + min;
```

EDIT 2:

if modulus is not defined for negative numbers:

```
if (input >= min)
    output = (input - min) % (max - min) + min;
else
    output = max - ((max - input) % (max - min));
```

Comment: Will this work if `(input - min)` results in a negative number?  I've read in C/C++, modulus on negative numbers isn't defined by the language (the sign of the result might be negative)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your request correctly, here's the simplest equation i could think of : `x % (max - min) + min`

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053/is-there-an-alternative-to-using-modulus-in-c-c) you can find some ways to optimize the modulo operator.